# One dimensional line R is a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Definition: Topological manifold
>
> A topological manifold is a locally euclidean, Hausdorff space with a countable basis for its topology.

An example given by my notes is the line $\mathbb{R}$ in one-dimension; claiming that $\mathbb{R}$ is a topological manifold.

Of course, for the one-dimensional line $\mathbb{R}$ to be a topological manifold, it must first be locally euclidean.
But no mention is made of the topology on the line $\mathbb{R}$. As such, I am unable to verify the homeomorphism from an open set in the line $\mathbb{R}$ to any open set in line $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Clarifications will be appreciated.

Comment: Is something wrong with the usual topology?

Comment: Well, standard topology I presume that is what you mean but it could have been any topology.

Comment: What very often happens in mathematical writing is that a "standard" notation such as $\mathbb{R}$ implicitly carries additional structure rather than just being a bare naked set. In this case, $\mathbb{R}$ implicitly carries the standard topology.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification